# this.collection.reset throwing error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I am trying to reset a collection but when I do I get the following error,

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

The code the fires this reset, is as follows,

```
// Main object for the entire app
```

window.APP = {

```
config: {
    api: {
        base:'http://app.local/api/v1/',
    }
},

// Create this closure to contain the cached modules
module: function() {
    // Internal module cache.
    var modules = {};
    // Create a new module reference scaffold or load an
    // existing module.
    return function(name) {
        // If this module has already been created, return it.
        if(modules[name]) {
            return modules[name];
        }
        // Create a module and save it under this name
        modules[name] = { Views: {} };
        return modules[name];
    };
}(),

init: function() {

    // :: app start :: //
    var app = POPS;
    var Module = app.module( $( '#popsapp' ).data('route') );

    // Creates a Master object in the global namespace so data can be passed in from the DOM.
    // This would be replaced with a master Router if we weren't using actual pages
    app.Initialiser = function( initialCollection ) {
        this.start = function() {

            //don't cache ajax calls
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

            console.log(Module);

            if(Module.Collection !== undefined) {
                this.collection = new Module.Collection();
                this.view = new Module.Views.Master({ collection: this.collection });
            } else {
                this.view = new Module.Views.Master();  
            }

            if(this.collection !== undefined) {
                console.log(this.collection);
                console.log(initialCollection);
                console.log(this.collection.reset( initialCollection ));
                this.collection.reset( initialCollection );
            }

            //moved this here so script runs after the DOM has loaded.
            //but script.js still needs completely removing.
        };
    }; 
}
```

};

// Entry point into the application
APP.init();

The error fires at `this.collection.reset( initialCollection)` if I log `this.collection` before that I can see a collection that is empty. The JSON I am trying to create my collection from is as follows,

```
[
{
    "name": "Organisation 1",
    "information": "This is some information about the organisation!",
    "notifications": "0",
    "add_all": "0",
    "created_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
    "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
    "type": "organisation",
    "clients": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Client 1",
            "information": "A client called Client 1",
            "add_all": "0",
            "created_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
            "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
            "type": "client",
            "pivot": {
                "organisation_id": "1",
                "client_id": "1"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Client 2",
            "information": "A client called Client 2",
            "add_all": "1",
            "created_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
            "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
            "type": "client",
            "pivot": {
                "organisation_id": "1",
                "client_id": "2"
            }
        }
    ],
    "projects": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Project #1",
            "description": "Descriptive text.",
            "total_cost": "0.00",
            "start_date": "2014-01-01",
            "finish_date": "2014-12-31",
            "run_number_days": "365",
            "num_days_from_year_start": "0",
            "color": "#92e807",
            "created_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
            "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
            "user_id": "1",
            "pivot": {
                "organisation_id": "1",
                "project_id": "1"
            }
        }
    ],
    "members": [],
    "teams": []
},
{
    "name": "Organisation 2",
    "information": "This is some information about Organisation 2",
    "notifications": "0",
    "add_all": "0",
    "created_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
    "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
    "type": "organisation",
    "clients": [],
    "projects": [],
    "members": [],
    "teams": []
},
{
    "name": "Client 1",
    "information": "A client called Client 1",
    "add_all": "0",
    "created_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
    "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
    "type": "client",
    "members": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "email": "user@domain.com",
            "first_name": "User",
            "last_name": "Name",
            "display_name": "",
            "initials": null,
            "remember_me": null,
            "login_type": "normal",
            "api_token": null,
            "created_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
            "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "pivot": {
                "client_id": "1",
                "user_id": "1"
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Client 2",
    "information": "A client called Client 2",
    "add_all": "1",
    "created_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
    "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
    "type": "client",
    "members": []
}
```

]

The json is perfectly valid, I am not sure what the problem is. Does anyone have any ideas, it reads like `this.collection` is not defined and that is why I can't run reset() on it, but I can see the colleciton when I log it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `collection.reset()` method takes as input an array of Backbone models. Your array (`initialCollection`) is just a generic JavaScript array.